# processing stdout in python

Tags: python

I have a script that keeps on dumping some values to the screen. Lets call this script 1

I need the values that gets dumped to the screen to be processed by another python script.Lets call this script2. I Script1 cant be stopped

I currently use **python 2.2** so it would be great if someone could provide an example without using subprocess

script 1 looks something like this

```
import sys
import os
i = 0
while 1:
    print i
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+"\n")
        i = i + 1
```

I need to write script2 such that every output generated by script1 is processed by script2

**-- edit --**

I need it to run on a legacy implementation ie no power shell just the command prompt available in Windows XP

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to say anything about code design here, because I really don't know what you are working on.

But for script2.py:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print "From stdin:", line
```

And then run (at least on unix/linux, if you are on windows, google "piping in powershell"):

```
python script1.py | python script2.py
```

Or did you want to do it within one python script? You could re-pipe `sys.stdout`, by simply replacing it with a class that has all the necessary methods (`write`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to process line by line:

```
# script2.py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
     print line # do something here with line
```

[edit] Finally, you simply pipe them:

```
python script1.py | python script2.py
```